# Is $X_t = tW\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$ a Martingale？If not, how could it be a Brownian Motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

As is proved, $X_t = tW\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$ is a Brownian motion. For example see Theorem 4.2 in this paper http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2012/REUPapers/Leiner.pdf

I'm just confused because it seems to me that this inverted Brownian Motion is not a  martingale. Take $s>t\ge 1$, then

$$\mathbb{E}_t[X_s] =\mathbb{E}_t\left[sW\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)\right] $$

But isn't $W\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)$ a piece of known information by time $t$? Therefore we can take it out from the expectation, but the past path of Brownian Motion could be anything, and it seems to me that $X_t$ is not a martingale. In my humble knowledge, Brownian Motion has to be a martingale, and it's a contradiction to me. Where was I wrong?

Comment: Brownian motion is a martingale w.r.t. its natural filtration, whereas using filtration $\sigma(W_t)$ for $t W(1/t)$ is unnatural.

Comment: Awesome, I guess that's what I'm missing. Can you briefly explain what is the natural filtration for $tW(1/t)$? Do you mind writing an answer so that I could choose your answer as the best?

Comment: $$\sigma(X_s;s\leqslant t)=\sigma(W(1/s);s\leqslant t)=\sigma(W(s);s\geqslant1/t)$$

Comment: @Did was fast enough to do that before me, so please expect answer from him.

Comment: @Did Do you mind explaining the second equality from your comment? Is the natural filtration of $X_t$ starting from infinity and goes to zero indexed of time?

Comment: The collection of random variables $W(1/s)$ indexed by every $0<s\leqslant t$ coincides with the collection of random variables $W(s)$ indexed by every $s\geqslant1/t$. This is why the second identity is rather direct.

Comment: Ok. So in terms of Martingale should I write

Comment: @Did Can you do me one more favor by explicitly writing out the martingale property in this case? When taking expectation of $X_s$ based on filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ where $t<s$, how to show it's a martingale.

Comment: *Which sigma-algebra* $\mathcal F_t$? This is kind of the whole point... If you think seriously about this, sooner or later you will need the fact that, for every $0<u<v$, $$E(W(u)\mid (W(s))_{s\geqslant v})=E(W(u)\mid W(v))=\frac{u}vW(v).$$

Comment: @Did Thanks, here's what I got, let $t<s$ then $$\mathbb{E}_t[X_s] = \mathbb{E} [sW(1/s) | (W(v))_{v\ge 1/t}] = \mathbb{E}[sW(1/s)|W(1/t)] = s \frac{t}{s}W(1/t) = tW(1/t) = X_t$$ May I ask how you get the last equality from the fact you provided?

Comment: You mean, $E(W(u)\mid W(v))=(u/v)W(v)$? Well, $(W(u),W(v))$ is a gaussian family, what do you know about the conditionings of these?

Comment: I guess you used the fact that $W(t) \sim N(0,t)$, is that what you meant?

Comment: @Did I'm late, but I understand now. It's a conditional expectation for a bivariate normal. Thank you very much for your guidance.